# quickly summing numpy arrays element-wise

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

Let's say I want to do an element-wise sum of a list of numpy arrays:

```
tosum = [rand(100,100) for n in range(10)]
```

I've been looking for the best way to do this. It seems like numpy.sum is awful:

```
timeit.timeit('sum(array(tosum), axis=0)',
              setup='from numpy import sum; from __main__ import tosum, array',
              number=10000)
75.02289700508118
timeit.timeit('sum(tosum, axis=0)',
              setup='from numpy import sum; from __main__ import tosum',
              number=10000)
78.99106407165527
```

Reduce is much faster (to the tune of nearly two orders of magnitude):

```
timeit.timeit('reduce(add,tosum)',
              setup='from numpy import add; from __main__ import tosum',
              number=10000)
1.131795883178711
```

It looks like reduce even has a meaningful lead over the non-numpy sum (note that these are for 1e6 runs rather than 1e4 for the above times):

```
timeit.timeit('reduce(add,tosum)',
              setup='from numpy import add; from __main__ import tosum',
              number=1000000)
109.98814797401428

timeit.timeit('sum(tosum)',
              setup='from __main__ import tosum',
              number=1000000)
125.52461504936218
```

Are there other methods I should try? Can anyone explain the rankings?

---

**Edit**

numpy.sum is definitely faster if the list is turned into a numpy array first:

```
tosum2 = array(tosum)
timeit.timeit('sum(tosum2, axis=0)',
              setup='from numpy import sum; from __main__ import tosum2',
              number=10000)
1.1545608043670654
```

However, I'm only interested in doing a sum once, so turning the array into a numpy array would still incur a real performance penalty.

Comment: I'm guessing that `np.sum` first creates and array and then sums it which would explain it's poor performance...  I'm guessing it would be the fastest if you had passed a `np.ndarray` to begin with.

Comment: And I'd expect reduce to beat `sum` by about 1/11 since it skips the `0 + tosum[0]` that is implicit in `sum`.

Comment: That makes sense. I start with a bunch of separate arrays, so turning them into a numpy array first would incur the same performance penalty as having sum do it for me (since I'm only doing the sum once).

Answer (score 5):

The following is competitive with `reduce`, and is faster if the `tosum` list is long enough.  However, it's not *a lot* faster, and it is more code. (`reduce(add, tosum)` sure is pretty.)

```
def loop_inplace_sum(arrlist):
    # assumes len(arrlist) > 0
    sum = arrlist[0].copy()
    for a in arrlist[1:]:
        sum += a
    return sum
```

Timing for the original `tosum`.  `reduce(add, tosum)` is faster:

```
In [128]: tosum = [rand(100,100) for n in range(10)]

In [129]: %timeit reduce(add, tosum)
10000 loops, best of 3: 73.5 µs per loop

In [130]: %timeit loop_inplace_sum(tosum)
10000 loops, best of 3: 78 µs per loop
```

Timing for a much longer list of arrays.  Now `loop_inplace_sum` is faster.

```
In [131]: tosum = [rand(100,100) for n in range(500)]

In [132]: %timeit reduce(add, tosum)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.09 ms per loop

In [133]: %timeit loop_inplace_sum(tosum)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you have thoughts on where the speedup comes from? Maybe it has less overhead than reduce? (I'm just adding ~10 large arrays together, so I'll probably stick with reduce, but this method is good to know for the future.)

Comment: Yes, less overhead: the in-place addition eliminates some object creation.  If you replace `sum +=a` with `sum = sum + a`, it becomes a bit slower than `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy sum is not awful, you are simply using numpy in the wrong way. You won't be able to make use of numpy's speed advantage if you combine normal python, functions (including `reduce`!), loops and lists with numpy arrays. If you want your code to be fast, you must *only use numpy*.

Since you did not specify any imports in your code snippet, I am not sure what the function `randn` is doing or where it comes from, so I just assumed that `tosum` should just represent a list of 10 matrices of some random numbers. The following code snippet shows that numpy is definitely not as slow as you claim it to be:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def test_np_sum(n=10):
    # n represents the numbers of matrices to sum up element wise
    tosum = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n, 10, 10)) # n 10x10 matrices, shape = (n, 10, 10)
    summed = np.sum(tosum, axis=0) # shape = (10, 10)
```

And then testing it:

```
timeit.timeit('test_np_sum()', number=10000, setup='from __main__ import test_np_sum')

0.8418250999999941
```

Comment: This is not answering my question or even providing any new information. I specified that I wanted to sum a list of numpy arrays, not a three-dimensional numpy array. You are doing the latter. I already investigated using a three-dimensional numpy array in the section titled "edit". Moreover, the benchmarks I presented are not fabricated. The code was exactly as slow as I claimed it to be. (The post is over 7 years old now, so perhaps things have changed since then.)

Comment: Ok, you are right in the sense that I didnt add any new information. If converting a list into a numpy array causes such a performance penalty, why not work solely with numpy arrays in the first place?